# Register different fingers for touch ID other than registered in settings iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, touch-id

I just touch ID integration and its my very first attempt, I'm following this [Tutorial](http://www.devfright.com/touch-id-tutorial-objective-c/) to integrate. Integrated perfectly fine but I've few queries.

- Can Apple allow us to register any finger other than allowed in settings to use lock feature.
- If anyone know about any tutorial or any helping information do and don't to use this feature which may hit apple guideline before publishing app.

Looking for help.

Thanks

Comment: The user can register fingers through the device settings. Your app cannot enrol fingers directly.